# Using go jobs with generic function

Tags: beginner, multithreading, go

I use the following which **works**( I remove the unnnecery parts to the question)

https://play.golang.org/p/OozjexJ4hZk

The program is doing the following:

> 1. run concurrent functions
> 2. each function should return response
> 3. calculate the response

I will add a logs and comments but I want to get feedback on the code.
What Im not sure if I use `clientA` and `clientB` in a clean way,but it works...

```
 package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    `net/http`

    "time"

    "github.com/gammazero/workerpool"
    `k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes`

)

type JobReact struct {
    name     string
    Duration time.Duration
    Info     interface{}
    Error    error
}

func (m *JobReact) Name() string {
    return m.name
}

type GenClient struct {
    ClientA http.Client
    ClientB kubernetes.Clientset
}

type ResultList struct {
    response http.Response
}

// Jobs holds job data
type Jobs struct {
    Name   string
    Runner func(*GenClient) JobReact
}

func wrapper(timeDuration time.Duration, reacts chan JobReact, jobs Jobs, genClient GenClient, ) func() {
    contextWithTimeout, tc := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeDuration)
    return func() {
        now := time.Now()
        go func(contx context.Context, cancelFunc context.CancelFunc, jobReacts chan JobReact, jobs Jobs, timer time.Time,
        ) {
            // Here I need to use the combined clients , should I use some interface? if yes how?
            runner := jobs.Runner(&genClient)
            runner.Duration = time.Since(timer)
            runner.name = jobs.Name
            if contextWithTimeout.Err() == nil {
                jobReacts <- runner
            }
            cancelFunc()
        }(contextWithTimeout, tc, reacts, jobs, now)
        select {
        case <-contextWithTimeout.Done():
            switch contextWithTimeout.Err() {
            case context.DeadlineExceeded:
                reacts <- JobReact{
                    name:     jobs.Name,
                    Error:    context.DeadlineExceeded,
                    Duration: time.Since(now),
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    // init clients
    genClients := GenClient{ClientA: ClientA(), ClientB: ClientB()}

    jobs := []Jobs{
        {
            Name: "job1",
            Runner: func(GenClient *GenClient) JobReact {
            // In this func I need to use client A
                GenClient.ClientA
                ...
            },
        },
        {
            Name: "job2",
            Runner: func(genClient *GenClient) JobReact {
            // In this func I need to use client b
                GenClient.ClientB
                ...
            },
        },
        {
            Name: "job3",
            Runner: func(genClient *GenClient) JobReact {
            // In this func I need to use Client A & client B
                GenClient.ClientB
                GenClient.ClientA
                ...
            },
        },
    }

    JobRes := make(chan JobReact, len(jobs))
    pool := workerpool.New(5)

    for _, worker := range jobs {
        pool.Submit(wrapper(time.Duration(time.Second * 10), JobRes, worker, genClients))
    }
    pool.StopWait()
    GetAllResponses(JobRes)
}

func GetAllResponses(wr chan JobReact) ResultList {
    for jobChannel := range wr {
        if jobChannel.Info != 200 {
            fmt.Printf("job %s: took '%d' sec response: %s\n", jobChannel.Name(), jobChannel.Duration.Seconds(), jobChannel.Error)
            return ResultList{response: http.Response{StatusCode: 500}}
        }
        fmt.Printf("job %s: took '%d' sec response: %s\n", jobChannel.Name(), jobChannel.Duration.Seconds(), jobChannel.Info)
    }
    return ResultList{response: http.Response{StatusCode: 200}}
}

func ClientA() http.Client {
    c := &http.Client{}
    return *c
}


func ClientB() kubernetes.Clientset {
    ....
    return *clientset
}
```